# Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, int, uint

I'm kinda new to C# coding and i have dealed lately with a problem and i want to ask for your help.
I have this piece of code from the link below.

http://pastebin.com/5jQe5tQs

My problem is at the finish line:

```
uint num = ((string_0[0] | (string_0[1] << 8)) |
            (string_0[2] << 0x10)) | (string_0[3] << 0x18);
```

Where i got this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

From what i know and read i see that the problem came from a value asigned for a int with is too big for the int values.
But from my little experience i do not know from what variable the value is not in the right format.
A more advised expert can help me please to fix the code?

Answer (score 3):

The result of the expression

```
((string_0[0] | (string_0[1] << 8)) | (string_0[2] << 0x10)) | (string_0[3] << 0x18)
```

is an `int`. You are putting it into a `uint`. Just make `num` an `int`, or cast the expression to `uint`.

What happens is, when you derefence a part of the string by using the `[]` operator, you fetch a `char`. Because shift operators for `char` [do not exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the value will be upgraded implicitly to `int` (upgrading is no problem, because there is no risk of loss of accuracy). So this part (as the others as well):

```
(string_0[1] << 8)
```

returns an `int`.

Comment: OK Already noticed that before but if i change num from uint to int i have the next error on num2. cannot convert from 'int' to 'uint' If i change num2 from uint num2 = metoda6(num, uint_0, uint_1); to int num2 = metoda6(num, uint_0, uint_1); i got a new error: The best overloaded method match for 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.metoda6(uint, uint, uint)' has some invalid arguments Here is the whole project (C#) VS2010 http://www70.zippyshare.com/v/45354586/file.html

Comment: You can always explicitly cast by using `(int)`.